# C++ console output in Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, console

When I run a C++ program in Netbeans on a Mac that has `cout` or `printf` statements the output is displayed in a terminal opened using X11. Is there a console built into Netbeans? If yes, how do I change the output to it?

Thanks,
Spencer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Under Project Properties -> Run -> Console Type you can choose "Output Window" instead of External Terminal.