# run java code with System.console class

Tags: java

How i will run this piece of java code????

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 *
 */

public class login{
    boolean authenticate(String u,char[] c){
        boolean x = false;
        if(u=="soumitra"&&c.toString()=="paas")
        {  x=true;}

        return x;

    }
public boolean login()

{int MAX_LOGINS=2;
  Console con = System.console();
  boolean auth = false;

  if (con != null)
  {
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
      String uname = con.readLine("Enter your username: ");
      char[] pwd = con.readPassword("Enter %s's password: ", uname);
      auth = authenticate(uname, pwd); // authenticate login info
      Arrays.fill(pwd, ' '); // delete password from memory
      con.writer().write("\n\n");  // output a couple of newlines
    } while (!auth && ++count < MAX_LOGINS);
  }
  return auth;
}
public static void  main(String args[]){
    login obj=new login();
    obj.login();

}
}
```

tried to run in Netbeansby rightclicking >>run....

got...
run:
**BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159655/compile-and-run-this-java-program

Comment: You shouls also have a look at java naming convention..good habit when learning. login should start as uppercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the code is in a file named login.java...

compile with:

```
javac login.java
```

should produce login.class, run with:

```
java login
```

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle has a tutorial.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html)
Try this in a terminal:

```
  javac login.java
  java login
```

Answer (score 0):

The Output window is typically also your console window.  Try making your Output window visible.

For C++, [there is an option in Netbeans for where Console should read from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863450/c-console-output-in-netbeans).